# Converting HTML to PDF buffer in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, html-pdf

I am trying to convert an HTML code that is returned by the "returnDefaultOfferLetter" function here into PDF buffer(that I will use for sending attachments in a mail) using html-pdf package. So, the problem is it works on localhost but on AWS elastic beanstalk server it throws me ASSERTION ERROR. So after some research, I got to know I need to specify phantomPath. I tried everything I could, but I haven't got any solution.

BTW one week before it was working on AWS, so don't know what's wrong now. Help me in finding some solution or suggest me any method or package to convert HTML into pdf *BUFFER*. (Please, don't ignore buffer)

```
const htmlToBase64Pdf = (req, res) => {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const offerLetterHTML = returnDefaultOfferLetter(req.body).toString(
            "utf8"
        );

        const pdfOptions = {
            format: "A3",
            phantomPath: "../../node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/bin/phantomjs",
        };

        pdf.create(offerLetterHTML, pdfOptions).toBuffer(function (
            err,
            buffer
        ) {
            if (err) {
                // console.log("err", err);
                reject(err);
            } else {
                // console.log("buffer", buffer);
                const base64Attachment = buffer.toString("base64");
                resolve(base64Attachment);
            }
        });
    });

    promise
        .then((resp) => res.send(resp))
        .catch((e) => {
            res.send(e);
        });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my npm library to do that

To install, run

```
npm i @hayzeddev/html-pdf-converter
```

```js
import { generatePdf } from '@hayzeddev/html-pdf-converter';


const htmlToBase64Pdf = (req, res) => {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const offerLetterHTML = returnDefaultOfferLetter(req.body).toString('utf8');

    generatePdf({ format: 'A3' }, offerLetterHTML).then((buffer) => {
      const base64Attachment = buffer.toString('base64');
      resolve(base64Attachment);
    });
  });

  promise
    .then((resp) => res.send(resp))
    .catch((e) => {
      res.send(e);
    });
};
```